How to fully close webdriver chorme in python
I made a parser using webdriver chrome. The site I'm parsing is dynamic, everything works fine, but there's a problem. The script does not completely close open chrome, that is, it stays in the task manager and loads the pc
Команда
driver.quit() 

закрывает chrome, но почему-то не полностью

Please provide a [mre] in an [edit] to your question. Also, would you mind editing the bits that aren't in English? (SO is an [English-only site].)

You can use Python's built-in os.system() command if you want to make sure Chrome is not running at all anymore.
os.system('killall -9 chrome.exe')
